# How do I calculate numbers like this into a real number?

Tags: calculator

I see numbers like this in calculators, but they don't mean anything to me.
How do I turn this number into a real number.

`9.223372e+18`

I'm not even sure what kind of math this is.

Comment: This is notation representing $9.223372 \cdot e^{18}$

Comment: that means: $9.223372 \cdot 10^{18}$ so thats a biiig decimal number. In practice, what you do is approximate that number... It depends on how much do u need to be precise!

Comment: @basket it is not., it is $10^{18}$ not $e^{18}$.  See [Scientific Notation on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)

Comment: It's scientific notation in "calculator" form.

Comment: https://www.lamission.edu/learningcenter/docs/mathlab/Symbols_Notations/what%20does%20E%20mean%20on%20a%20calculator.pdf

Comment: If someone can find an older or more general question about scientific notation using e's, feel free to link that instead.